# SMB encryption for connection from internet

Tags: networking, server, samba, encryption

I use Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS with all updates and use built-in Samba 4.1.6. Because I use Samba from internet, I set `smb encrypt = mandatory`. This is fine, works great (even if I see login name when I listen the communication, but password and all data is encrypted).

But because I have slow comp (Atom D330), maximum speed is around 8-9 MB/s. When I turn off smb encryption, speed is about 60-70 MB/s.

Is there any option how to encrypt all connections from the internet, but don't encrypt connection from local network (192.168.88.0/24)? Encryption on the local network is useless and greatly reduce the speed.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to disable encryption, as well as direct access from the Internet, and use a VPN instead.  Another is to set up a second instance of samba ( on an alternate port ) just for serving access from the Internet and configure that one to require encryption, but not the local instance.

Comment: Using VPN is not a solution for me. I don't want to setup and use VPN only because of Samba, which supports encryption.

And using two instances of Samba also is not a solution, because this means to have two different connections and every disk connected twice. It is security by obscurity.

Comment: @LukasBeran, no, it is not obscurity through obscurity, nor connecting to every disk twice.  It is to have two different means of connecting to a disk; one that is encrypted ( and thus secure ) , and once which is not ( and thus fast ), and choosing between the two basted on whether you are at home or away.